# Embeding several YouTube videos on website

Tags: youtube-api

I have a website where I will have several images, clicking on the image will load its corresponding YouTube video.

What is the best and most effective way of doing this?

Comment: Right now I am trying to just use the Iframe API to load a video on the page. I am however, having difficulties with that. http://jsfiddle.net/tHsWC/1/

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to make the thubmnails normal `<img>` tags, and then when they (or a container `<div>`) are clicked, dynamically load the YouTube iframe Player.

I have a few projects that are examples of that. You can take a look at the [YouTube Topics Explorer](https://gdata-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gdata/topic-explorer/dist/index.html) (search for a topic) or [YouTube Direct Lite](http://ytdirectlite.appspot.com/static-min/submit.html) (go to the `My YouTube Videos` tab after logging in), both of which are open source.

The specific code that handles this in the Topic Explorer examples is [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-samples/source/browse/trunk/gdata/topic-explorer/app/scripts/controllers/main.js#239).